# What is the canonical way to manually fire page_view in Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

My website is a single page app (SPA) that never changes browser history or the page title. Therefore, it's my understanding that I have two options if I want to capture page_view events:

1. Add browser history and a unique title for every virtual page.
2. Manually fire a page_view in SPA code.

I'm going with option 2.

I've read numerous articles on how to do this, and they tend to converge on similar advice, but they're always a little different from each other. This is probably because most were written soon after GA4's release. After trying most of the steps in these articles, I'm not convinced I've set up virtual pageviews correctly. Unfortunately, [the official documentation provides little guidance](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11403294?hl=en):

> Alternatively, you can always explicitly set page parameters when sending a page_view event to ensure accuracy and clarity.

When it comes to the official documentation, [I've only been able to find guidance on doing this with gtag.js](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11403294?hl=en), but I'm not using that. I'm using Google Tag Manager (GTM). Here are the steps I've taken and my rationale for taking them (besides an article telling me to do so). After this list, I'll explain why I think it's not working correctly.

1. Login to GTM
2. Create a Google Analytics GA4 Configuration but **uncheck** "Send a page view event when this configuration loads". I do this because, if I'm going to manually send `page_view` events, I don't want this configuration to send a duplicate.
3. Create a custom event trigger named "Page Loaded". This allows me to control when I fire this trigger. There's nothing special about it yet. Here's how it looks:
   [image]
4. On my SPA, I add this line above the GTM tag in the `<header>`:

   ```html
   <script>
     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   </script>
   <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
   ```
5. Elsewhere in my code, I manually use that `dataLayer` to fire my trigger:

   ```js
   dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'Page Loaded',
     'page_url': ...,
     'page_title': ...,
   });
   ```
6. Back in GTM, I create data layer variables for those two `page_*` fields:
   [image]
7. I create a `page_view` tag that reacts to this trigger and uses those variables.
   [image]
8. I click the preview button to see how it's working.
   [image]

Now, as far as I can tell, this tag is firing at the right time and passing all the right information. But here's why I think there's something wrong:

If I view my *other* tag, the *google analytics hit* information has `Page Location` and `Page Title` values of the *actual* page, not the virtual page (aka the custom event I created). This other tag's trigger looks like this:

[image]

The tag looks like this:

[image]

And the Google Analytics Hit looks like this (on the Tag Assistant page):

[image]

Those red arrows have the value of the actual page.

Is there some step/configuration I'm missing? I would expect all the tags to use the `Page Title` of my `page_view` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, that's cuz either the fields aren't being inherited from the settings variable (I have noticed that behavior in GA4 before) or the values of your DL variables are not set at that point (which is unlikely).

An obvious fix for it would be just adding your fields to the click tag and be done with it.

The way I do GA4 tags is by making one single tag. For everything. All its content are variables, including the name of the event. And all the logic for it is either in regex lookup tables or in CJS. Or in both: CJS that uses rLUTs.

Now it may seem complicated and overengineered, but now the size of your GA4 set up is small (remember: the size of the container is limited), it's easy to manage if you love your JS (all logic is in one place) and you don't need to iterate through all your dimensions every time you need a new event to fire.

So I basically treat a GA4 event tag as a config variable. In your case, you can even merge the pageview and the click events into one.

Also, not having history changes is a really poor practice and I would switch the site engine completely. It will cause dramatic issues in other places, like SEO.

Comment: "the **fields** aren't being inherited from the **settings variable**" I'm not familiar with these terms. Are they GA4 concepts (as opposed to GTM)? I'm not sure what CJS or rLUTs stands for either. Regarding your single tag idea, doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of using GTM? Why not use gtag.js for that instead?

Comment: I stumbled upon the answer to why GTM might be preferred: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/reasons-why-you-should-use-google-tag-manager/#gref

Comment: They are GTM concepts. Fields are the `event properties` that you're setting for your tags. settings variable is what UA used to use, GA4 tags use a config tag instead, but the fields inherited from it will stuck at the values they were when the config tag fired, therefore, you want to set your properties explicitly.

Comment: Ah, I read what you just said in a blog before. I think I understand what you are saying, but there's one last thing I don't know how to do: how/where do I find the name of the ga4 property I'm trying to override? In the preview, it's called "Page Title" (that picture with that big red box), but through experimentation, I've figured out I need to send an event parameter named `page_title`  to change that value.  Where do I find the mapping reference?

Comment: yeah, well the mapping reference... uh, again, GA4 lacks documentation severely, especially when you start doing edge case implementations, but here, this sould be ample for your purposes: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages and a bit more here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en Don't forget about the referrer. It's important for attribution.

Comment: FWIW, I'm quickly seeing the advantage of a single tag for everything. It's quite annoying to have to copy the same event parameters to each tag I create when I generally want to know that same information.

Comment: Yes. There's an alternative... you can always make a new tag, export the json, edit it and copy over the dimensions from your old tag to the new one. I do it for some clients/implementations, but I do prefer just having a few tags cuz it helps keeping the container size intact and is easier to manage for me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your newly made `Event tag` isn't a `Configuration tag`, and you haven't set your `Configuration tag`'s `page title/location` to the values you wish.
Since all your other events only refer to `Configuration tags`, they're bound to **inherit its default settings**, not what you set up in your `Event tag`.

If you want to change the `page_title` and `page_location` for all your events, my thoughts are that you should either:

1. Set `page_title` and `page_location` parameter values in your `Configuration tag`'s **Fields to Set** menu, **not** in an `Event tag`

-> By doing so **all** your events' `page title and locations` will be set to whatever value you wish

-> Refer to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11262438

2. Manually modify `page_title` and `page_location` via **Configuration > Modify events** menu

-> Refer to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872?hl=en&ref_topic=9756175#zippy=%2Cin-this-article
and https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11091026?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

By the way, I recommend tagging only what you need with different tags for each purpose. If you capture too much data, GA will sample it, thus making it useless. Also, using different tags for each purpose makes it easier to modify the data you wish to collect according to the circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. It's been a while, but isn't there some field(s) in the configuration tag that once set, can't be modified later in the session? I just want to make sure it's not that `Fields to Set`.

Comment: There are no fields that are completely set for an entire session (at least, not that I know of). `Fields` that identify the session itself like `Session ID` logged automatically could apply; I'm not sure.
Btw after some research, I've found `Fields` set on a `Configuration tag` can't be completely modified by `Event tags` that fire afterward and only refresh when the `Configuration tag` fires again. If modified on an `Event tag`, the modified value is applied to the corresponding `Event` itself only. Refer to https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095?hl=en

Comment: I'm confused: `If modified on an Event tag, the modified value is applied to the corresponding Event itself only` Does that mean for this event the value would be different, but if the next one doesn't set that field, it'll be the value in the configuration tag?

Comment: Yes, this has been confirmed through a few tests done on my end. If there is a `field` you would like to reset at certain points, you could separate the `page_view` event by creating a `page_view` `Event tag` and triggering the `Configuration tag` when field resets are necessary. (Refer to "Consideration #2" section of this post: https://ken-williams.com/guide/installation/should-you-manually-set-the-page_view-event-in-an-app-web-property-using-gtm/)

Comment: It's been quite a few months, but I think it would help me (and many others) if you explained how you tested these things yourself. Was this done through GTM's "preview?"